# Canvas animation doesnt work fluently. What can i do?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

Since I added  `o: Math.random()*(1 - 0.1) + 0.1 //opacity` for charge random opacity values the animation doesn't work fluently. What can I do to prevent this? How do i make my script more effeciently regarding to the performance?

```
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var W = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    var H = 550;
    var mp = 45; //max particles
    var particles = [];
    //var rotate = 180;

    reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                   window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
                   window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

    for ( var i = 0; i < mp; i++ )
        {
            particles.push({
                x: Math.floor(Math.random()*W), //x-coordinate
                y: Math.floor(Math.random()*H), //y-coordinate
                d: Math.floor(Math.random()*(12 - 1) + 1), //density
                r: Math.floor(Math.random()*(70 - 10) + 10), //radius
                o: Math.random()*(1 - 0.1) + 0.1 //opacity
            })
        }



    function animate() {
        reqAnimFrame(animate);
        for ( var i = 0; i < mp; i++ )
            {
                var p = particles[i];
                p.x += p.d;


                if(p.x >= W + p.r){
                    p.x = -300;
                    p.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*H);
                }
                draw();
            }
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        for ( var i = 0; i < mp; i++ )
            {
                var p = particles[i];
                ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(51,51,51," + p.o + ")";
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                ctx.fill();
                //ctx.moveTo(p.x,p.y);
                //ctx.lineTo(p.x + 150, p.y + (-180));
                //ctx.lineTo(p.x + 300, p.y);
            }    
    }
    animate();
    };//onload function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling draw within your update loop once for each particle, which leads to a mp*mp cost instead of a mp cost.
First thing to do is to call draw only once per particle, so do not call it within your update loop, but just once at the end of the update.

Notice you can gain some performances by changing the context's globalAlpha instead of creating a new color.

Answer (score 2):

I make the jsfiddles [`one`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wPQmn/) and [`two`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wPQmn/1/).

In [first fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wPQmn/) there is no `closePath` function calling, in [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wPQmn/1/) it calling.

In [first fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wPQmn/) devtools timeline show extra memory usage 7 MB per second (after 1s calling CG in your case, IMHO): from 10 MB to 17 MB

In [second fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wPQmn/1/) timeline show extra memory usage 2 MB from `beginPath` to `closePath` functions (near 130ms): from 10 MB to 12 MB. But in this case CG don't call.

I think it will be better to add `closePath` function, to prevent GC calling. And use less number of particles for old browsers, because as for me (MacBook Pro, Chrome) all works fine and fps was 60(maximum).

Comment: Interesting. i'm really surprised. I thought beginPath meant that you were closing the previous path... seems i was wrong !

Comment: About `beginPath`: it starts subpath only. Every new beginPath will create one more subpath only. But `closePath` add current subpath to main path and close subpath, ie free some memory.

Comment: I [`added`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/wPQmn/2/) globalAlpha like GameAlchemist answered...And memory extra usage is 0.1MB :)